# Should null strings on Booksleeve redis client cause timeouts?

Tags: c#, redis, booksleeve

So I have this unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestNullString()
{
    String expectedTestValue = null;
    var uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    redis.Wait(redis.Strings.Set(db, uid, expectedTestValue));
    var testValue = redis.Wait(redis.Strings.GetString(db, uid));

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedTestValue, testValue);
}
```

The outcome is a timeout.  Is this supposed to happen or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: change your expectedTestValue initialization to 
var expectedTestValue = string.Empty;

Comment: I changed it back to what it was supposed to be.  An empty string is not the same thing as a null string.

Comment: I'll have a look in the morning; that should work fine.

Comment: use the string.IsEmptyOrNull for checking the empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis has no concept of `null`. Either a string *is* (i.e. `"abc"` or `""` - zero-length strings are fine), or it *is not* (i.e. the key does not exist).

The "bug" here is that BookSleeve does not check for a `null` value to `.String.Set` and throw an exception. That will be rectified imminently.

What is happening currently is that the code is failing when writing the command to the stream - in particular, the redis binary protocol means that you declare the number of arguments **before** sending the data, i.e. (simplified) "SET", "2", "key", "value" - and since it never writes the value, the server doesn't even get the chance to send a "that isn't valid" reply; as far as the server is concerned, it is still waiting for an extra parameter.